# Adicionar uma chave/valor em um objeto em typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho um objeto array que quero adicionar na posicao 0 uma chave e valor nele.

Tentei algo como:

```
this.testeobj//meu objeto
this.testeobj[0].push({oi: 'teste});
```

Comment: [Trabalhando com objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc quer um array de objetos

```
this.testeobj = [] //seu array de objetos
this.testeobj.push({oi: 'teste});
```

O push é uma propriedade somente do array, ela vai inserir na ultima posição do seu array o valor passado que no seu caso é um objeto.

O exemplo abaixo passando a posição é só quando vc quer colocar o valor na posição exata do array

```
this.testeobj[0] = {oi: 'teste};
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Só para ficar claro para o autor da pergunta: a segunda versão não adiciona um item, e sim substitui. Ou seja, se existir algo na posição 0 da array, esse algo será substituído pelo novo conteúdo.